# Use dataset observations in where clause of Proc SQL when reading Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sas

I'm pretty new to SAS having only just completed a fundamentals course, so this is probably an easy one.

I am pulling data into SAS from and Oracle database and want to know if I can use an underlying list of observations in a dataset in a where clause  of a Proc SQL query to only read relevant data.

Working in a bank I have a list of account numbers (char format) that I would like to pull all the transaction data for into a new data table.  The Oracle database contains thousands of account numbers, but I only need to read certain account numbers on a daily basis, which will change from day to day (so can't be hard coded).  We are pulling to data through using the Proc SQL function and I would like to iterate the Proc SQL process several times over for each account number in my underlying dataset with the new account number populating in the where clause each iteration.

I have looked into Macro Variables, but don't really understand how they would work or if they would work.  Can anyone help?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate an example:

```
%let AccNums="100","200","300"; /* this creates & populates a macro variable */

proc sql;
connect to odbc as mycon
   (datasrc=ora7 user=testuser password=testpass);

select * from connection to mycon
  (select x,y,z from MYTABLE 
    where Account_number in (&AccNums) /* this resolves the macro variable*/
);
quit;
```

See documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001355234.htm) for further info.  Note that your suggested approach (iterating for each account number) would be inefficient as would involve multiple source queries (and corresponding network traffic).  Better to hold the account numbers in one or more macro variables and submit that way.  Note that a single macro variable can only hold 65,534 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to oracle using a `libname` connection, then you can read into SAS the list of account numbers (presumably these are in a text file or excel file, or can be put into one) and join that table to the oracle table.

```
libname myoradb oracle <connection string>;

proc sql;
 create table accts as 
   select * from myoradb.accts O, acctsIwant A
    where O.acctno=A.acctno;
quit;
```

Assuming `acctsIwant` is a SAS dataset (that you read in from whatever location makes sense).

Comment: This is a simpler approach, but from previous experience working in banks the risk here is that myoradb.accts is a HUGE table and this could incur a lot of network traffic trying to pull it across into SASWORK..

Comment: although perhaps the SAS/Access engine for Oracle would be clever enough to try and prevent this

Comment: This shouldn't require any additional network traffic relative to your method, as I understand it; SAS should translate the query and push it up to Oracle.  Obviously if it doesn't then don't do it this way :)  I would prefer then rather than using macro variable, though, to push the data to a temporary table in Oracle.

Comment: The Access engine can indeed translate queries (and functions etc) into DB specific / optimised syntax, but the thing here is that ACCTSIWANT is a SASWORK table, so will it be able to push that table into the DB in order to do the join?  Perhaps - I don't know..

Comment: From the OP's perspective - I'd recommend trying both approaches and seeing which one is quicker for your environment / situation.